# Как сделать вывод аргументов в команде, если после ввода команды идет переход в другую функцию?

Tags: python, telebot

После ввода команды `/reg` должна быть проверка на наличие следующего аргумента `1`. Но почему-то проверка не работает и похоже из-за перехода в другую функцию. Как можно решить эту проблему?

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['reg', 'registration'])
def registration_message(message):
    registration_group(message)

def registration_group(message):  # Регистрация беседы
    args = message.text.split()

    if len(args) < 2:
        bot.reply_to(message, text='Используйте: /reg Группа')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Регистрация беседы')
```

Comment: bot.register_next_step_handler(message, registration_group) - попробуйте так.